# Samsung QX410-j01 Touchpad is not working

Tags: 12.04, synaptics

I have been using Ubuntu on a Samsung QX410-j01 laptop for ~2 years (mostly v11.04). Yesterday, I upgraded to 11.10 and eventually to 12.04. Now, only the left click on the touchpad works. I cannot use right click. I cannot drag or resize any windows.

I would appreciate any help.

I tried to use synclient. It did not change. Here are the current settings:

```
LeftEdge                = 117
RightEdge               = 2817
TopEdge                 = 88
BottomEdge              = 4000
FingerLow               = 1
FingerHigh              = 1
FingerPress             = 256
MaxTapTime              = 180
MaxTapMove              = 147
MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
SingleTapTimeout        = 180
ClickTime               = 100
FastTaps                = 0
EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
VertScrollDelta         = 67
HorizScrollDelta        = 67
VertEdgeScroll          = 1
HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
CornerCoasting          = 0
VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
MinSpeed                = 1
MaxSpeed                = 1.75
AccelFactor             = 0.0596
TrackstickSpeed         = 40
EdgeMotionMinZ          = 30
EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 160
EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 268
EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
TouchpadOff             = 2
LockedDrags             = 0
LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
RTCornerButton          = 2
RBCornerButton          = 3
LTCornerButton          = 0
LBCornerButton          = 0
TapButton1              = 1
TapButton2              = 3
TapButton3              = 0
ClickFinger1            = 1
ClickFinger2            = 1
ClickFinger3            = 0
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.100007
CircScrollTrigger       = 0
CircularPad             = 0
PalmDetect              = 1
PalmMinWidth            = 8
PalmMinZ                = 100
CoastingSpeed           = 20
CoastingFriction        = 50
PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
ResolutionDetect        = 1
GrabEventDevice         = 1
TapAndDragGesture       = 1
AreaLeftEdge            = 0
AreaRightEdge           = 0
AreaTopEdge             = 0
AreaBottomEdge          = 4445
HorizHysteresis         = 16
VertHysteresis          = 16
ClickPad                = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved.

I followed [these instructions](http://www.theorangenotebook.com/2012/02/call-for-testing-clickpad.html).

Since some part of the touchpad was working, I only performed the following steps:

1. `wget http://people.canonical.com/~cndougla/enable-clickpad.sh`
2. `chmod a+x enable-clickpad.sh`
3. `./enable-clickpad.sh <device name|device id>`

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same model laptop with Elantech touchpad. I don't think this really worked on 11.04; it was recognized as a PS/2 mouse and as I recall it was too sensitive and the cursor was flying around all the time.

Starting with 11.10, the kernel has support for the Elantech touchpad. It may work a bit differently than you're used to, but since it's recognized as a touchpad now, it can be configured with the `synclient` utility.

You can for instance open a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) and run:

```
synclient RBCornerButton 3
```

This will generate a right click when you tap the bottom right corner of the touchpad. I also use:

```
synclient Tapbutton2 3
```

This generates a right click when you tap with two fingers anywhere in the pad.

I also suggest you enable palm detection:

```
synclient PalmDetect=1
synclient PalmMinZ=100
synclient PalmMinWidth=8
```

You can tweak the PalmMinZ and PalmMinWidth to your liking, until the driver correctly ignores accidental contact

You can read about available settings by issuing this command:

`man synaptics`

Answer (score 0):

Right now, I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 on a Samsung QX410.

Here is my conf to get my touchpad working the same on Windows

```
synclient Clickpad=1
synclient HorizEdgeScroll=1
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient VertTwoFingerScroll=1
synclient RightButtonAreaLeft=1500
synclient RightButtonAreaRight=2846
synclient RightButtonAreaTop=1400
synclient RightButtonAreaBottom=1771
```

Hope this helps.